# How to debug safari app extension on Xcode when pid could not be attached

Tags: xcode, safari, safari-extension

I started an empty safari app extension in Xcode, I didn't change any code from the boilerplate.
When I run this new and empty extension and choose safari to open it, something went wrong:

```
Could not attach to pid : “13069”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: Error 1
--
Error 1
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
--
```

I am totally new to xcode and safari extension, hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clean the build folder with <kbd>Cmd + Shift + K</kbd> and rerun the extension project, then it works.
But still, don't know what caused this problem.